# C: Struct with an array of repeated pointers does not point to the correct location and has garbage values

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have a struct named "deck" with has an array with structs. These are the structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum suits {Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades} suits;
typedef struct card{

    int rank;

    //Suit: Clubs ♣, Diamonds ♦, Hearts ♥, Spades ♠
    suits suit;
}card;


#define SUITAMOUNT 4
#define DECKLENGTH 13
#define CARDSINADECK DECKLENGTH*SUITAMOUNT
typedef struct deck {
    card cards[CARDSINADECK];

} deck;

#define DECKAMOUNT 8
#define CARDSINASHOE DECKAMOUNT*CARDSINADECK
typedef struct shoe {
    uint topOfShoe;

    card * cards[CARDSINASHOE];

} shoe;
```

I create the "deck" like this:

```
static deck createDeckOfCards()
{
    deck deckOfCards;

    for ( suits suitType = Clubs; suitType <= Spades; suitType++) {

        uint offset = DECKLENGTH * suitType;
        for (int rankNumer = 0; rankNumer < DECKLENGTH ; rankNumer++) {
            uint posInArray = rankNumer + offset;

            /* card *newCard = createCard(rankNumer + 1, suitType); */
            card newCard = { .rank = rankNumer + 1, .suit = suitType };
            deckOfCards.cards[posInArray] = newCard;
        }
    }

    return deckOfCards;
}
```

This works fine. All the cards are stored in the deck struct correctly. However, when I try to store the pointers to deck's array, I get garbage values.
I store them like this:

```
static shoe createShoeFromDecks(deck deckOfCards)
{
    shoe shoeOfCards;
    for (int nShoe =0; nShoe < DECKAMOUNT; nShoe++) {

        uint offset = CARDSINADECK * nShoe;
        for (int rankNumer = 0; rankNumer < CARDSINADECK; rankNumer++) {
            uint posInArray = rankNumer + offset;

            card *cardptr = &deckOfCards.cards[rankNumer];
            shoeOfCards.cards[posInArray] = cardptr;
        }
    }

    return shoeOfCards;
}
```

This iterates over 'deck's card array and I store a pointer to that card (`card *cardptr = &deckOfCards.cards[rankNumer];`) in shoe (`shoeOfCards.cards[posInArray] = cardptr;`)

Minimal reproducible example:

```
void main()
{
    deck deckOfCards;
    deckOfCards = createDeckOfCards();

    shoe shoeOfCards = createShoeFromDecks(deckOfCards);

    for (int i = 0; i < CARDSINASHOE; i++ ) {
        printf("%d %d \n", shoeOfCards.cards[i]->rank,shoeOfCards.cards[i]->suit);
    }
```

I get random garbage values:

```
1 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
1 1
2 1
925927168 224639505
4 1
-1662575432 32764
-1662579072 32764
0 0
-1662575416 32764
-523731496 21946
-1869656064 32690
(...)
```

Some of these values change every time I run the program.

How could I store the pointers correctly?

Comment: The code uses `DECKAMOUNT`  and `CARDSINASHOE` but does not define them. Can you please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem, rather than incomplete fragments?

Comment: `CARDSINASHOE` is also missing and so is `uint`.

Comment: Those are both constants. I've edited the question. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Aside: ideally a macro should parenthesise expressions, so `#define CARDSINADECK (DECKLENGTH * SUITAMOUNT)`

Comment: If you make a [mre] it'll be clear what goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue is in your function **createShoeFromDecks**:

```
static shoe createShoeFromDecks(deck deckOfCards)
{
    shoe shoeOfCards;
    for (int nShoe =0; nShoe < DECKAMOUNT; nShoe++) {

        uint offset = CARDSINADECK * nShoe;
        for (int rankNumer = 0; rankNumer < CARDSINADECK; rankNumer++) {
            uint posInArray = rankNumer + offset;

            card *cardptr = &deckOfCards.cards[rankNumer];
            shoeOfCards.cards[posInArray] = cardptr;
        }
    }

    return shoeOfCards;
}
```

You're passing deckOfCards as value, which will result in creating a local deckOfCards variable that is destroyed after exiting the function (removed from the stack).

```
card *cardptr = &deckOfCards.cards[rankNumer];
```

This will return a pointer to a local variable.

To fix this you can simply change the prototype of your function to pass your deckofCards object by reference (or by pointer) :

```
static shoe createShoeFromDecks(deck* deckOfCards)
{
    shoe shoeOfCards;
    for (int nShoe =0; nShoe < DECKAMOUNT; nShoe++) {

        uint offset = CARDSINADECK * nShoe;
        for (int rankNumer = 0; rankNumer < CARDSINADECK; rankNumer++) {
            uint posInArray = rankNumer + offset;
            // Note that -> which means dereferencing a pointer.
            card *cardptr = &(deckOfCards->cards[rankNumer]);
            shoeOfCards.cards[posInArray] = cardptr;
        }
    }

    return shoeOfCards;
}
```

And then when you call it, pass the address instead of the variable itself :

```
shoe shoeOfCards = createShoeFromDecks(&deckOfCards);
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm almost sure that you'll get better results.